# Some links on meta fade away on mouseover

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Links in the "X people chatting" box and related questions section fade away to an obscure color on mouseover, as if they don't want to be clicked.

[image]

[image]

Perhaps a leftover from [the old 2-tone background design](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/some-design-changes)?

I'm on Google Chrome 14.0 / Safari 5.1, Mac OS X 10.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Hooray for the next deployment! The animation effect is awesome, just expecting it to go the other way in terms of contrast.